# ¿Requiere el verbo "comprobar" que el sujeto sea algo con capacidad de raciocinio?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

En una conversación ayer, alguien dijo algo parecido a esto:

> ...y me llamó por teléfono. Eso comprueba que no le caigo mal.

Mi cerebro automáticamente cambió "comprueba" por "demuestra", dado que la frase, tal y como se planteó, me sonó rara. Pero ¿por qué? Según el DLE:

> **[comprobar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A3csXkj)**
>
> 1. tr. Confirmar la veracidad o exactitud de algo.

Con esa definición, la frase simplemente indica que "eso confirma que no le caigo mal", que la veo bien planteada, al igual que si simplemente dijera "eso prueba que no le caigo mal". Así que insisto: ¿qué puede tener la frase "eso comprueba que no le caigo mal" para que me suene rara?

Lo más que se me ocurre es que el hecho de confirmar la veracidad o exactitud de algo solo puede ser llevado a cabo por alguien que tenga algo de raciocinio; de hecho las frases que se me ocurren de ejemplo con el verbo "comprobar" siempre tienen como sujeto al menos a un ser vivo:

> Y así el león comprueba que no puede competir con el veloz antílope.

O como mucho impersonales, pero implicando indirectamente siempre a una persona:

> Se comprueba así que la sal se diluye en agua.
>   <sub>(Lo comprueba al menos una persona: quien escribió la frase.)</sub>

¿Necesita el verbo "comprobar" un sujeto con capacidad de raciocinio?

---

<sub>Nota: con la de veces que he oído la palabra "[raciocinio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V0FJllU)" y acabo de descubrir que es la "facultad de [raciocinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V0FBOLL)", que no lo había oído nunca...</sub>

Comment: A mí también me suena correcto usar sólo sujetos vivos/animados, o su equivalente (*El algoritmo primero comprueba que el número ingresado sea positivo*). El significado lo da el uso.

Comment: @pablodf76 interesante la comparación que haces de un algoritmo como algo con capacidad para efectuar una comprobación.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Deformación cuasi-profesional quizá.

Comment: Mi gato comprobó hoy una vez más que el miembro de la familia que menos paciencia tiene de todos es él.

Comment: Y así mi gato comprobó que la capacidad de raciocinio no es esencial para comprobar algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso he tenido que recurrir a la RAE. El tuit de consulta fue [el siguiente](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/872829530402160640):

> ¿Por qué me suena raro "Eso comprueba que le caigo bien"? ¿Necesita el verbo "comprobar" un sujeto con capacidad de raciocinio?

La respuesta de la RAE se hizo esperar más de 24 horas, un tiempo superior al que (a mí particularmente) me tiene acostumbrado, y fue [la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/873099348929765376):

> Sí, la definición del DLE no lo deja claro, pero es así. En el contexto que propone, el verbo apropiado es «probar».

Así pues, la RAE confirma que el verbo *comprobar* necesita un sujeto con capacidad de raciocinio, sea este un ser humano, un animal, o incluso un algoritmo (que, a fin de cuentas, está diseñado por un humano, así que es como si el que comprueba fuese el humano que lo programó, aunque esto es una discusión filosófica que va más allá del propósito de este sitio).

Comment: Más que raciocinio, creo que es `discernimiento`, aunque estoy siendo un poco _tiquismiquis_ acerca de lo que es _razonamiento_ y qué capacidades podemos atribuir a ciertas entidades. En cualquier caso, +1. Muy interesante.

Answer (score 0):

Bajo mi punto de vista se puede escribir los siguiente:

> El software que he realizado comprueba que los ficheros estén dentro de los directorios.

En este caso el sujeto no es un ser vivo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder **realmente** a la pregunta (es el software un "sujeto con capacidad de raciocinio", como discute la pregunta?) y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Answer (score 0):

No creo que haya que meterse en berenjenales acerca del raciocinio y la [sintiencia](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/sintiencia-termino-valido/) para explicar por qué te chirría...

> ...y me llamó por teléfono. Eso comprueba que no le caigo mal.

Veamos (escojo las acepciones que nos atañen):

- [**Comprobar**(1)](https://dle.rae.es/?id=A3csXkj): confirmar la
  veracidad o exactitud de algo.
- [**Demostrar**(2)](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CAqWkEB): probar,
  sirviéndose de cualquier género de demostración.
- [**Probar**(3)](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UEEVr9n): justificar,
  manifestar y hacer patente la certeza de un hecho o la verdad de algo
  con razones, instrumentos o testigos.

Como son verbos que se usan para expresar hechos del mundo relativos a la información y la verificación (qué información sirve para verificar el qué) puede parecer que son verbos intercambiables, pero hay una diferencia fundamental entre el primero y los otros dos.

Lo que no explican las definiciones del DLE es la sintaxis de cada verbo, es decir, **qué funciones** (dentro de la oración) **deben asumir los elementos relevantes** para que la frase tenga sentido.

1. *Comprobar*: si *A comprueba B* es que *A* analiza información, la contrasta con *B*, y confirma algo.
2. *Demostrar* o *probar*: si *A demuestra o prueba B* es que la información de *A*, en buena lógica, confirma *B*.

El sujeto de *comprobar* **recoge información** y elabora un resultado. Los de *demostrar* o *probar* **contienen información** que permite elaborar un resultado.

Se explica perfectamente que tu cerebro proteste y te proponga los verbos "demostrar" o "probar" en sustitución de "comprobar".

---

Pero como el título de la pregunta es si el sujeto de *comprobar* ha de tener capacidad de raciocinio, mi opinión **personal** es que no.

Sí que creo que ese sujeto ha de poseer algún tipo de **lógica interna** (simple o complejísima) que, tras captar la información, emita un juicio al respecto. Por eso, no creo que su uso para *software*, circuitos o máquinas *comprobadoras* sea un caso de antropomorfización.

A mi entender, la definición de *comprobar* está bien como está y el que contestó a @Charlie se equivoca. Si acaso, algún ejemplo aclaratorio en las definiciones de los tres verbos no estaría de más.