# ¿Existen verbos que no admitan complemento indirecto? En caso afirmativo, ¿existe alguna denominación para ellos?

Tags: gramática, solicitud-de-término, objetos-indirectos

Mientras terminamos de debatir si [el sujeto del verbo comprobar debe ser algo con capacidad de raciocinio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21167/12637), me he dado cuenta de una cosa: los verbos *[comprobar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A3csXkj)* ("confirmar la veracidad o exactitud de algo") y *[demostrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CAqWkEB)* ("probar, sirviéndose de cualquier género de demostración", siendo *[probar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UEEVr9n)* a su vez "justificar, manifestar y hacer patente la certeza de un hecho o la verdad de algo con razones, instrumentos o testigos") tienen significados similares. En última instancia, como se ha visto, los dos refieren el hecho de verificar la certeza de algo.

Ambos verbos son transitivos: el objeto directo es lo que se comprueba o demuestra. La diferencia que les veo es que el verbo *comprobar* se usa casi siempre sin complemento indirecto, mientras que *demostrar* sí puede hacerlo:

> *Yo le demostré a Pepe que podía hacerlo.*
>   <sup>(Frase correctamente construida.)</sup>
>
> *Yo le comprobé a Pepe que podía hacerlo.*
>   <sup>(Frase que me suena rara.)</sup>

Ni siquiera tengo claro si la segunda frase es correcta o no, dado que habitualmente quien comprueba algo (o lo que comprueba algo) lo hace para sí mismo:

> *Yo comprobé que podía hacerlo.*
>   <sup>(Frase correctamente construida.)</sup>

Pero la pregunta va más bien por otro camino: ¿existen verbos que no admitan complemento indirecto? Si es así, ¿existe alguna denominación para ese tipo de verbos que no admiten complemento indirecto, similar a la clasificación "transitivo/intransitivo"?

---

Actualización: coincidiendo con el comentario de Brian, me di cuenta, después, que sí se puede usar el verbo *comprobar* con complemento indirecto:

> —¿Podría mirar si hay vuelos disponibles para mañana?
>   —Un momento que se lo compruebo ahora mismo.

Lo cual no invalida la pregunta en sí.

Comment: como no tengo ni idea de si existen verbos como pides, no voy a poner esto en una respuesta, pero la segunda frase creo que solo suena rara porque no tiene mucho sentido, sin embargo, puedes decir "se lo comprobaron" y suena correcto (no se me ocurre que pueden representar en esta frase el CD y el CI, pero es correcta)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo No me suena natural "comprobar" con OI. Cambiaría tu oración final por: *Un momento que se lo confirmo ahora mismo.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen verbos **monotransitivos** que sólo admiten objeto directo. Me parece que son escasos porque inclusive aquéllos que no aceptan un OI argumental (seleccionado por el verbo) suelen aceptar un OI no argumental de tipo dativo.

Algunos ejemplos que he encontrado hojeando el "Manual de gramática del español" de Ángela Di Tullio que ni siquiera aceptarían un dativo son:

- Manuel **adora** la música rock.
- **Temíamos** la llegada de Julián.
- **Necesito** un secretario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas son los verbos impersonales. Los relacionados con la meteorología son un buen ejemplo:

- Va a *llover* mucho.
- Justo antes de *amanecer*.
- *Nieva* en los Picos de Europa.
- Mientras no *granice*, podemos ir en coche.
- *Relampaguear* (se dice le cayo un relámpago a alguien)
- *Anochecer*, *tronar*,...

Comment: *le* va a llover mucho

Comment: @BrianH. Pero ya no es meteorológico, es figurado y ya no es impersonal, estas usando la segunda definición de la RAE.  *intr. Dicho de algunas cosas, como trabajos, desgracias, etc.: Venir, caer sobre alguien con abundancia. U. menos c. tr.*[...] *Más frecuente es su empleo como verbo personal con el sentido figurado de ‘caer algo desde arriba como si fuera lluvia’*

Comment: hmm, ¿y cual sería el sujeto en "le va a llover"? ¿se consideraría "el agua" como sujeto omitido? (pregunto en serio, no se si parece sarcasmo, no es la intención)

Comment: @BrianH. pero en "le va a llover", ¿"le" es complemento directo o indirecto?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo yo diría que indirecto: le va a llover *a él/ella*

Comment: @BrianH. tengo mis dudas porque, como tú preguntas, falta el objeto directo (qué le va a llover), que sería "el agua", pero no sé si "el agua" es el objeto directo o el sujeto (usando la segunda acepción de "llover", como dice Alex).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo en tu ejemplo "qué le va a llover" te acabas de contestar a ti mismo. `qué` puede ser el CD.  
(debo añadir que no soy mas que una persona a la que le gustaba y daba bien el análisis sintáctico/gramatical cuando estaba en el instituto, no soy ninguna autoridad de ningún tipo xD)

Comment: En todo caso, y como dice @BrianH, aunque un verbo sea impersonal, lo único que quiere decir es que no existe un sujeto, pero sí puede haber alguien sobre quien recaiga la acción (incluso aunque se refiera a la acción meteorológica): "Me amaneció de camino al trabajo", "Nos nevó mientras subíamos a la cima", "Les granizó de vuelta a casa"...

Comment: @AlexBcn Inclusive cuando su sentido es meteorológico algunos verbos impersonales pueden aceptar un sujeto, por ejemplo: *Están lloviendo soretes de punta* (modo vulgar de decir que está lloviendo mucho) o *Granizaron pelotas de golf* (granizo de gran tamaño).

Comment: Tuvimos mala suerte el día de la fiesta.  Nos llovió a cántaros.